# Some IPhone address book related questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I've some questions related to address book.

1) How Can I design some UIButtons, which are as same as in the address book buttons?

If you observe all the "Phone numbers" buttons in the Contact's info view, the upper and below buttons only has the curved edges not all the buttons.

2) How can I show the default image (if a contact doesn't have any image) as same as address book?

3) What is the color (seems as blue but not) of a phone number if it is in the dialed or received list?

If you received/dialed a contact's number and then you see the "Info" details, you can notice the color of that particular (which you dialed) number. The color is close blue/cyan but not.

Any help appreciated.

Thanx and regards,
Prathap.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some tutorial, I found that something exactly what I want.

1)How Can I design some UIButtons, which are as same as in the address book buttons?

Ans: Customize your button's drawing for the same. (implement the"draw" method of UIButton in your customized class)

2) How can I show the default image (if a contact doesn't have any image) as same as address book?

Ans: Currently there is no way to the same. To show the default image you need the same PNG image and add it to your view controller.

3) What is the color (seems as blue but not) of a phone number if it is in the dialed or received list?

Ans: I don't know about the color :-).